# jQuery EasyAutocomplete not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am using the jQuery EasyAutocomplete plugin from http://easyautocomplete.com/.

I am using a JSON file to get data. It does not seem to filter the results properly. It only searches through the first couple of records, for example it only shows the first 10 and if the search string is not within those records it ignores the rest.

Also, how can I search through either the airportid or the airportname? i.e If it matches either the airportid or the airportname?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
<input type="text" id="airportid">
<input type="text" id="airportname">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        url: "airportinfo.json",
        getValue: function(element) {
            return element.name;
        },

        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function() {
                var selectedItemValue = $("#autocomplete").getSelectedItemData().name;
                var selectedItemValue2 = $("#autocomplete").getSelectedItemData().airportid;
                $("#airportname").val(selectedItemValue);
                $("#airportid").val(selectedItemValue2);
            },
        }
    };

    $("#autocomplete").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

**my JSON file**

```
[{
    "airportid": "JASB",
    "size": "medium_airport",
    "name": "John Bay Airport",
    "lat": "18.57500076",
    "lon": "36.5333004",
}, {
    "airportid": "JAAD",
    "size": "closed",
    "name": "Adelaide Airport",
    "lat": "-12.68310165",
    "lon": "16.2942009",
}, {
    "airportid": "JAAE",
    "size": "small_airport",
    "name": "Aberdeen Airport",
    "lat": "-12.46670151",
    "lon": "14.06669998",

}]
```

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I missed something from the documentation. I'm putting it here in case someone else may have the same issue in the future:

```
list: {
    onChooseEvent: function() {
        var selectedItemValue = $("#autocomplete").getSelectedItemData().name;
        var selectedItemValue2 = $("#autocomplete").getSelectedItemData().airportid;
        $("#airportname").val(selectedItemValue);
        $("#airportid").val(selectedItemValue2);
    },
    match: {
        enabled: true
    },
},
```

I forgot to add "Match:{enabled:true}